# How can I get rid of the distance when I'm using list-style-type: none?

Tags: theme-development, css, html

I am using the following code (output html) to get my comments displayed.
But there is a space because of the `list-style-type: none;` I used.

How can I get rid of this?

This is [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tm8fzwvp/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake in your CSS. .commentlist should be .comment-list